Setting Up Eclipse Mosquitto on Kubernetes
I'm currently developing a microservices-based API using Node.js, Docker, and Kubernetes. For inter-service communication, I’ve implemented NATS Streaming Server. Additionally, I use Ingress-Nginx as a reverse proxy to manage traffic within the API.
The API communicates with ESP32-based devices indirectly. Currently, it sends HTTP requests to a Raspberry Pi, which then acts as an MQTT broker, forwarding commands via Mosquitto to all subscribed ESP32 devices on specific topics.
I want to simplify this architecture by removing the Raspberry Pi from the equation and deploying Mosquitto server directly as a containerized service in Kubernetes. My goal is to enable direct two-way communication between the API and the ESP32 devices through MQTT.
I’ve already prepared a Kubernetes manifest for deploying the Mosquitto server, but I've been getting an error when running skaffold that says: missing Resource metadata, and when I remove the manifest from the kluster everything works fine.
Here’s my Kubernetes manifest:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mosquitto
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mosquitto
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mosquitto
          image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1883
            - containerPort: 9001
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/mosquitto/
              name: config
            - mountPath: /mosquitto/certs/
              name: certs
            - mountPath: /mosquitto/data/
              name: data
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: mosquitto-config
        - name: certs
          secret:
            secretName: mosquitto-certs
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mosquitto-data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-config
data:
  mosquitto.conf: |
    allow_anonymous true
    persistence true
    persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
    log_dest stdout

    # MQTTS listener
    listener 1883
    protocol mqtt

    cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    keyfile /mosquitto/certs/tls.key
    certfile /mosquitto/certs/tls.crt

    # WS Listener
    listener 9001
    protocol websockets
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-mqtts
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
  ports:
    - port: 1883
      nodePort: 30883
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mosquitto-ws
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mosquitto
  ports:
    - port: 9001

